# Разбиение строки/списка по лямбде

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно разделить строку/список, используя лямбду?

Например:

**1.** у меня есть строка `123-456-789`, для нее я определяю функцию `lambda x: x == '-'` и получаю `[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]`

**2.** у меня есть список `['123', '-', '456', '-', '789']`, для него я определяю функцию `lambda x: x == '-'` и получаю `[['123'], ['456'], ['789']]`

**3.** у меня есть список слов `['Сообщество', 'здесь', ',', 'чтобы', 'помочь', 'вам', 'с', 'конкретными', 'проблемами', 'по', 'программированию', ',', 'алгоритмам', ',', 'языкам', 'программирования', '.']` и я хочу удалить пунктуацию, поэтому задаю `lambda x: x in ',.'`, результат:

> [['Сообщество', 'здесь'], ['чтобы', 'помочь', 'вам', 'с',
> 'конкретными', 'проблемами', 'по', 'программированию'],
> ['алгоритмам'], ['языкам', 'программирования']]

Пример без реализации:

```
items = '123-456-789'

parts = split_by_func(items, lambda x: x == '-')
print(parts)
# [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример реализации через [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from typing import Iterable, Callable, List

def split_by_func(items: Iterable, func: Callable) -> List[List]:
    return [list(x[1]) for x in groupby(items, func) if not x[0]]
```

Тест:

```
tokens = [
    'Сообщество', 'здесь', ',', 'чтобы', 'помочь', 'вам', 'с', 'конкретными', 'проблемами',
    'по', 'программированию', ',', 'алгоритмам', ',', 'языкам', 'программирования', '.'
]
parts = split_by_func(tokens, lambda x: x in ',.')
print(parts)
# [['Сообщество', 'здесь'], ['чтобы', 'помочь', 'вам', 'с', 'конкретными',
# 'проблемами', 'по', 'программированию'], ['алгоритмам'], ['языкам', 'программирования']]
```